# How do you replace all numbers in a string with a defined character in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

---

How would you replace all numbers in a string with a pre-defined character?

Replace each individual number with a dash "-".

```
$str = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
```

Desired output:

```
"John is -- years old and donated $--.--!"
```

I am assuming `preg_replace()` will be used but I am not sure how to target just numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution using `strtr`(to translate all digits) and `str_repeat` functions:

```
$str = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
$result = strtr($str, '0123456789', str_repeat('-', 10));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
John is -- years old and donated $--.--!
```

---

As alternative approach you may also use [***array_fill***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) function(to create *"replace_pairs"*):

```
$str = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
$result = strtr($str, '0123456789', array_fill(0, 10, '-'));
```

---

**http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php**

Comment: That is a good idea. I like it. You could just use '----------'. It would be quicker, but difficult to count.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/766275)

```
<?php

$str = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
echo preg_replace("/\d/", "-", $str);
```

**OR:**

```
<?php

$str = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
echo preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "-", $str);
```

**Output:**
`John is -- years old and donated $--.--!`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with a normal replace:

```
$input   = "John is 28 years old and donated $40.39!";
$numbers = str_split('1234567890');
$output  = str_replace($numbers,'-',$input);
echo $output;
```

just in case you were wondering. Code was tested and it works. The output is:

> John is -- years old and donated $--.--!

No need for 'obscure' regular expressions. Do you remember where the slashes and braces go and why?